# Is there a way to automatically import all missing files in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I am working on an old project that I am converting to PSR-4 namespacing. It is taking a very long time to manually go through files, find classes that are missing a `use` statement, and then import it. I know that PhpStorm offers automatic import when you type/paste a class in, and I can  hover on each class individually, but I have thousands of files to go through.

Does PhpStorm have a method to go through the entire project and attempt to import all missing files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: inspecion]

Run inspection on.. And then, Choose inspection scope for "Whole project"